# AngularJS filter refresh for placeholder

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I am using filter to localize my page. 
AngularJS filters only refresh when the key is changing unless they are expressions (or objects) and then they are evaluated on every digest cycle.
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

So instead of writing this:

```
<div>{{'name' | localFilter}}</div>
```

I used a little trick and wrote the 'name' as expression to trigger filter refresh on every digest cycle. I defined variable localize=true

```
<div>{{localize && ('name' | localFilter)}}</div>
```

and it worked. BUT it doesn't work when I need to localize placeholder, as you can see from the snippet the localized values got the ja-Jp prefix, but the placeholder didn't

```
<input id="username" type="text" ng-attr-placeholder="{{localize && ('example_email' | localFilter) }}" />
```

[image]
Any ideas?
I know about stateful filters - that doesn't work for me because I have many other pages where I will just reload for the lozalisation to happen

Comment: are you using angular or angularjs? you seem to mix the 2 within the post

Comment: AngularJS **is not** Angular; See the tags descriptions.

Comment: could you please clarify your question to the correct language?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon you mean framework?

Comment: @Baruch yeah, my bad

Comment: Sorry didn't read carefully through the tags description. I meant AngularJS

Answer (score 1):

In `angular.js` you can use `ng-attr-X` attributes for render of `X` attributes.

Try to use `ng-attr-placeholder` for that reason.

```
<input id="username" type="text" 
       ng-attr-placeholder="{{localize && ('example_email' | localFilter) }}" />
```

Comment: Did you seen documentation link in the question? Only one thing is wrong here - angular tag

Comment: yet the code samples provided are valid angular code, plus there are 2 angular tags on the question and only 1 angularjs tag

Comment: no, it is not, but the rest of the question suggests its angular not angularjs

Comment: OP just confused by our tags, what's wrong with my answer, if it's about angularjs?

Comment: Just cause OP confused the tag and / or the documentation link, doesn't mean this answer is wrong. Hell, even the title of the question says `AngularJS`.

Comment: It's AngularJS question

Comment: I tried the ng-attr-placeholder and it didn't solve my problem

Comment: Can you add localFilter source into your question?

Comment: the filter is working because other things gets localized. it's just finding the key in a dictionary and return the value as a result

Answer (score 1):

Well, as the comment say in vp_arth's answer. The tags are confusing. If this is an  AngularJS question, then refer to vp_arth's answer, if not, you need to do this:

```
<input id="username" type="text" [placeholder]="localize && ('example_email' | localFilter)" />
```

This way Angular understands that the attribute value to the element will be an expression and not a string. This way, it can be any type (boolean, number, string, function, object, etc...)

Comment: adding the `[]` around placeholder should then mean you dont need the `{{}}` within the quotes

Comment: @mast3rd3mon Yea, you're right. I just copy/pasted OP's code. I edited my answer. Cheers.